# How to change the columns into rows

Tags: python, pandas, rows

I have this data frame:

```
Name  type1  type2  type3  ...  typeN  color

John  8.7  0  NA  ...  56  blue

Andy  45  34  9.7  ...  NA  yellow
```

I need to change it to be like:

```
color  typeName  Name  value
blue  type1  John  8.7
blue  type2  John  0
blue  type3  John  NA
.
.
.
blue  typeN  John  56
yellow  type1  Andy  45
yellow  type2  Andy  34
yellow  type3  Andy  9.7
.
.
.
yellow  typeN  Andy  NA
```

I'm a little bit confused about how to do that, any help please?

Comment: You want to melt it. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Name', 'color'], var_name='typeName')
```

---

```
    Name    color   typeName    value
0   John    blue    type1       8.7
1   Andy    yellow  type1       45.0
2   John    blue    type2       0.0
3   Andy    yellow  type2       34.0
4   John    blue    type3       NaN
5   Andy    yellow  type3       9.7
6   John    blue    typeN       56.0
7   Andy    yellow  typeN       NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

This is related to data reshaping. See workflow below using stack (alternative to melt),

**Sample Data**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John','Andy'], 'type1':[8.7,45],'type2':[0,34], 'color':['blue','yellow']})
```

```
result = df.set_index(['Name','color'])
           .rename_axis('typeName',axis=1)
           .stack(dropna=False)
           .reset_index(name='value')
```

**Output**

```
    Name    color   typeName    value
0   John    blue    type1   8.7
1   John    blue    type2   0.0
2   Andy    yellow  type1   45.0
3   Andy    yellow  type2   34.0
```